# Twitter Bootstrap - Centering content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://elosource.herokuapp.com/

As you can see on my test page, the content is aligned in the left site. I want to have it in the center.

I read though
http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html but it didn't work for some reason.

My content looks like this

```
<div class="content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/180x1200">
            </div>
        <div class="span12">
                @content
            </div>
            <div class="span">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/180x1200">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And my css:

```
.content {
background-color: #fff;
display: block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of setting widths to things. That's why I like using inline-block for centering.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">
    <p>I'm so centered</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should set a width on your .content as well. Something like this:

```
.content {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 1340px;
}
```

tried it in the chrome inspector and works fine...

Comment: Yeah you are right it works with 1920x1080. But on my laptop its completely destroyed. Everything is stacked. Something percentage based would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

Change the css to this:

```
.content {
background-color: #fff;
display: block;
text-align: center;
}​
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/x6vPH/

Comment: Hm, theoretically it should work but it doesn't. Maybe twitter bootstrap has a higher priority on something with ´left-pull´ as default. I don't know. Any ideas? Btw I can't use text-align because it will center all of my texts in my content. I just want to center the content itself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to centre the @content? If so try this.

```
    <div class="span12 pagination-centered">
```

Answer (score 1):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rfkrocktk/hcQ48/). i got it from [twitter issue tracker](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/399)

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="alert-message block-message info" style="margin:10px">
        <h3>Centered Layouts</h3>
        <div class="alert-message block-message success span12 offset1">
            <p>Layout for <code>span12 offset1</code></p>
        </div>
        <div class="alert-message block-message success span10 offset2">
            <p>Layout for <code>span10 offset2</code></p>
        </div>
        <div class="alert-message block-message success span8 offset3">
            <p>Layout for <code>span8 offset3</code></p>
        </div>
        <div class="alert-message block-message success span6 offset4">
            <p>Layout for <code>span6 offset4</code></p>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert-message block-message info" style="margin:10px">
        <h3>Split Layouts</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="alert-message block-message success span6">
                <p>Layout for<code>span6</code></p>
            </div>
            <div class="alert-message block-message success span4 offset4">
                <p>Layout for <code>span2 offset6</code></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

hoping this helps

Answer (score 0):

create a .center class and wrap a div around whatever you want to center.

```
.center {
 text-align: center;
}

<div class="center">
  ... stuff ...
</div>
```